# How to handle soft keyboard switching language for a layout containing edittexts of two different languages in android activity?

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, direction

I have a screen which contains edit texts, some of them need to be handled with English soft keyboard, and some of them need to be handled with the Arabic keyboard, how can I specify switching input language on switching between these edit texts while focused?

Answer (score 2):

[Ali Nawaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5729661/ali-nawaz), you can do sth like this:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
    edtText.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_RTL);
       OR 
    edtText.setLayoutDirection(View.LAYOUT_DIRECTION_LTR);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ali for the answer, also do you know any solution to switch soft keyboard input language because that's what exactly I am looking for...

Comment: you have to create your own keyboard for that.